# Upgrade to postgres 10 wanting to use checksums

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-10

I have a postgresql 9.3 instance that I am wanting to upgrade to postgresql 10. I have a command that I think should work but it includes checksums in it. My old instance doesn't have checksums enabled (could it even be at all? Forget was too long ago) and that is preventing my dry run from working right.

**Error message**

```
Performing Consistency Checks on Old Live Server
------------------------------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

old cluster does not use data checksums but the new one does
Failure, exiting
```

**My command stripped of real paths**

```
time ${PGBINNEW}/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=${PGBINOLD} --new-bindir=${PGBINNEW} --old-datadir=${PGDATAOLD} --new-datadir=${PGDATANEW} --old-port=${PGPORT} --new-port=${PGPORT} --jobs=$(nproc | awk '{ {print ($1 > 4) ? 4 : ($1 == 1 ? 1 : $1 - 1)} }') --link --username=postgres --check
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

Happened to me during pg_upgrade. I Just disabled the checksum with this:

```
$ pg_checksums -d /var/lib/postgres/data/
pg_checksums: syncing data directory
pg_checksums: updating control file
Checksums disabled in cluster
```

In my case /var/lib/postgres/data is the data directory. Yours might be different.

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve above 
old cluster does not use data checksums but the new one does
Failure, exiting 
error : while installing new data cluster

.initdb -k -D /your data directory path/
then perform the upgradation